# Azure Logic App will not start

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am creating a Logic App and have problems in the first step.

I want to trigger it by http post. 
The structure is very simple.
[image]

however after saving i see this,
[image]

I don't know what it means by "Not Found". If I click "enable", it will auto-disable in 1 minute.

If I click Select Trigger->Manual right after I enable it, there's an error
[image]

This should be a quite simple task: enable the logic app, whenever an http request arrives, send out an Http request. But it cannot be done that easily.

Comment: Can you please share the code view that is generated? I tried your steps from screen shot and I am able to save the logic app and the "Select Trigger" after saving shows "manual".

Comment: @Clarke, it seems that your logic app is not associated with any hosting plan. This is the reason that you are seeing a 'Not found' message. It is possible that the resources were not provisioned correctly. This is why running the logic app fails as well. It gets disabled immediately since there is no hosting plan association.

Comment: Thank you for the above response.  It seems I didn't quite get how Logic App or Azure eco system works before. Anyway we moved to AWS Simple Workflow at last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have your app service plan suitable for running Logic Apps.From the screenshot your provided, i noticed that there is no App Service Plan associated with it.
**You will need to recreate this logic app**, or try to move it to another resource group that has a plan to it.
you can't change the Service Plan in the Logic App settings like what you can do with Web Apps

**Edited**

I tried replicating this and moving it to a different resource group but it didn't resolve the issue. You will need to recreate the Logic App.